# Returning const string&

Tags: c++, reference, return, constants

While analyzing some code I found something like this

```
auto foo() const -> std::string const&
```

It's a bit confusing for me. What does that mean exactly?
To be more precisely I mean about the part:

```
std::string const&
```

Comment: Do you know how return type deduction works?

Comment: a reference to std::string which text you can not change only read

Comment: It's a function returning a `const` reference to a `std::string` – thought there wouldn't have been need to apply trailing return type, alternative (classic) variant of: `std::string const& foo() const`.

Comment: Not sure where you are confused, but since it wasn't mentioned yet: `const std::string&` and `std::string const &` are exactly the same

Comment: Look up `trailing return type` in your favorite [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Some people disregard the tradition of writing `const` on the left, purportedly because it makes types easier to read.

Comment: [Similar question was asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73961495/what-does-const-in-a-function-template-definition-mean).

Answer (score 0):

It's the return type: a reference to a const string.

Comment: Reference to const string should be like that:
const std::string&
Am I right?

Comment: You can put the `const` either before or behind the type name. So `const std::string&` is equal to `std::string const&`